# Win GDI DrawText bad rendering

Tags: winapi, text, rendering, gdi

Until today I've been using `GetTextExtentPoint32` to measure the text to render, prior to rendering using DrawText.

Since I now need to render a multiline text, I must use `DrawText` with `DT_CALCRECT` (as `GetTextExtentPoint32` ignores newline chars).

However this causes the text to render differently, mostly by reducing character interspacing. For example:

[image: Two text renderings]

The bottom rendering is after the change.
I've isolated the problem to find that just by calling the first `DrawText` while using the original output from `GetTextExtentPoint32` - the problem remains.

Here's the reduction of the sequence of calls:

```
::GetTextExtentPoint32(...); // Result is used
::DrawText(... DT_CALCRECT); // Result is unused
BITMAPINFOHEADER bih = { size values from GetTextExtentPoint32 };
hBitMap = ::CreateDIBSection(... (BITMAPINFO*)&bih, ...); 
::SelectObject (hdc, hBitMap);
::DrawText(...); // Render the text
```

Note, it doesn't matter if I remove the `DT_CALCRECT` in the second line. The call to `DrawText` **before** `CreateDIBSection` seems to be the culprit.

What else should I be trying?

Comment: If this is the bug I think it is, then this is a bug where some internal floating point positioning state remains somewhere in GDI. This same bug also causes buggy character spacing in GDI+ with .NET framework in certain situations (particularly tooltips). Some years ago I have found the exact issue, and found a hint in some article, but unfortunately I cannot remember the details.

Comment: Trying to sift through some old programs; not sure but you might be able to work around it by selecting a different HFONT into the DC, and then selecting back to the font you actually want to draw, probably right before the "real" `DrawText` call.

Answer (score 0):

How about font quality and precision flags in LOGFONT during font creation? Did you try to see if it makes a difference?

Also I didn't understand the last sentence. Are you saying that if you remove DrawText (... DT_CALC) or move it **after** CreateDIBSection the results are different, without bad character spacing?

Comment: I meant two things:
(1) If I keep the DrawText in place (2nd line) but use it without DT_CALCRECT, the problem remains.
(2) If I move the second line to after CreateDIBSection, the problem disappears

Comment: This is indeed weird. But to be honest if I were to render text into a bitmap I would usually have a bitmap setup code first and then all the drawing. So as per your finding, this kind of flow would work without strange results.

Comment: I wish I could do that. However the bitmap setup code requires passing the render size, thus the text measuring...